# mysql2 gem cause the 'utc' error when run on Rails3

Tags: mysql2, ruby-on-rails-3

I run Rails app on Windows7.
at first, I use Rails3 + Mysql2.
but, cause an error when I test on console:

> rails console -s
>
> Photo.where(:id => 2)

```
ArgumentError: argument out of range
    from C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:640:in `utc'
```

I'm sure that is mysql2's bug. because when I switch to mysql gem, everything runs ok.

who can help me. thanks

Comment: we need more information about your error.